# How to add onclick function to my search bar

Tags: javascript

I got a simple code for a search bar from this site, I was wanting to add a function to it so that when the user clicks on the search icon on the search bar it redirects them to a URL. Here is the code

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display:none">
      <symbol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="sbx-icon-search-13" viewBox="0 0 40 40">
    <path d="M26.804 29.01c-2.832 2.34-6.465 3.746-10.426 3.746C7.333 32.756 0 25.424 0 16.378 0 7.333 7.333 0 16.378 0c9.046 0 16.378 7.333 16.378 16.378 0 3.96-1.406 7.594-3.746 10.426l10.534 10.534c.607.607.61 1.59-.004 2.202-.61.61-1.597.61-2.202.004L26.804 29.01zm-10.426.627c7.323 0 13.26-5.936 13.26-13.26 0-7.32-5.937-13.257-13.26-13.257C9.056 3.12 3.12 9.056 3.12 16.378c0 7.323 5.936 13.26 13.258 13.26z"
    fill-rule="evenodd" />
      </symbol>
      <symbol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="sbx-icon-clear-3" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
    <path d="M8.114 10L.944 2.83 0 1.885 1.886 0l.943.943L10 8.113l7.17-7.17.944-.943L20 1.886l-.943.943-7.17 7.17 7.17 7.17.943.944L18.114 20l-.943-.943-7.17-7.17-7.17 7.17-.944.943L0 18.114l.943-.943L8.113 10z" fill-rule="evenodd" />
     </symbol>
    </svg>

    <form novalidate="novalidate" onsubmit="return false;" class="searchbox sbx-custom">
      <div role="search" class="sbx-custom__wrapper">
    <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search your website" autocomplete="off" required="required" class="sbx-custom__input">
    <button type="submit" title="Submit your search query." class="sbx-custom__submit">
      <svg role="img" aria-label="Search">
        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#sbx-icon-search-13"></use>
      </svg>
    </button>
        <button type="reset" title="Clear the search query." class="sbx-custom__reset">
      <svg role="img" aria-label="Reset">
        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#sbx-icon-clear-3"></use>
      </svg>
    </button>
      </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.querySelector('.searchbox [type="reset"]').addEventListener('click', function() {  this.parentNode.querySelector('input').focus();});
</script>
```

I don't know anything about JavaScript. Could someone tell me how I would do this and most importantly where I would place the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Answer (score 1):

You can add javascript code anywhere inside `head` or inside `body`. The ideal way to do it is to add you JS code before `body` tag ends, after all your other HTML.

As for the functionality you want, your code

```
document.querySelector('.searchbox [type="reset"]').addEventListener('click', function() {  this.parentNode.querySelector('input').focus();});
```

clears the search input and focuses on it when the button `reset` is clicked on.

To make your submit button redirect somewhere, we need more information, but the general idea would be like this:

```
document.querySelector('.searchbox button[type="submit"]').addEventListener('click', function() {  window.location.assign('your url here');});
```

this will take the user to that url and they can come back to the previous page by hitting back.

If you use `window.location.replace()` it will do the same thing but the history of the old page will be replaced by the new URL.